# South Korean servers can't find any games?

Tags: dota-2

From yesterday evening Dota 2 can't find any games, normal or ranked. When I try to find a normal match the timer is keep resetting after 3-5 minutes of searching.

Has anyone heard about this problem or also experiencing it?

Comment: Did you try another server? Just to know if your problem server sided

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing it once every 6 months on Europe servers but fortunately, being server based, I could play on a different server (east or west) most of the times.

I would recommend testing other servers when this happens (if the ping is acceptable of course) and/or wait for the server to be up and running.